# Can you assign your own GUID for a list?

Tags: list, guid

I am trying to assign my own GUID to a list I am creating but am having difficulties. Currently I am creating the list with the code:

```
site.Lists.Add(CONFIGURATION_LIST_NAME, CONFIGURATION_LIST_DESCRIPTION, SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
```

Which returns a GUID, but I would like to supply my own. Is there anyway to do this in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: why do you need to assigne GUID yourself?

Comment: So I can have a static class that contains all my GUIDs, and CTID's. I guess I can just grab the returning GUID from the site.Lists.Add() method and use it then.

Comment: I would definitely recommend letting SharePoint assign the GUID and just pulling it after the fact. Its a much safer and better guaranteed to avoid issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the guid for the list is used directly by SharePoint to store items in the SQL-tables common to all site collections/sites in a Content database.
If they allowed you to assign that yourselves it would cause problems of people storing information in multiple lists with the same Guid which SharePoint would the read for all of the lists. Which might also allow you to read/write information which you shouldn't have access to.

Even Microsoft got all the checks in place and prevented you from creating new lists with the same guid (also when you moved site collections to new content databases). It would mean that activating your feature in one site collection would disallow it in any other in that database.

So all in all I think it's good you can't control it